# Django session variable not working when using AJAX

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, session, django-sessions

I have to delete an item and, for that, the user clicks in some "Delete" button in the page and Javascript makes an AJAX request (including the CSRF token in the header of the request) for a Django view to proceed with the deletion. My Django view is processing the request properly and deleting the item. But, in the same view, I do the following:

1. Delete the item
2. Put a message on the request.session['message']
3. Redirects to the 'list page'

The 'list page' view checks if there is some 'message' in request.session and returns it to the page to show in some *alert* to the user.

However, this mechanism is not working for this case, when using AJAX. It is like both the 'delete' view session and the 'list page' session are not the same, because it does not find the 'message' in the request.session.

Here are some of the files involved.

**urls.py**:

```
...

urlpatterns = [
        path('agenda', views.agenda, name='agenda'),
        path('<int:reuniao_id>/excluirReuniao', views.excluirReuniao, name='excluirReuniao'),
]
```

**views.py**:

```
def agenda(request):
    reunioes = ReuniaoEmpresa.objects.all()

    if 'message' in request.session:
        message= request.session['message']
        del request.session['message']
    else:
        message= ''

    context = {
        'reunioes' : reunioes,
        'message' : message
    }

    return render(request, 'agenda/agenda.html', context)


def excluirReuniao(request, reuniao_id):
    reuniao = get_object_or_404(ReuniaoEmpresa, pk=reuniao_id)    
    reuniao.delete()

    request.session['message'] = 'Reunião excluída com sucesso!'

    return redirect(reverse("agenda:agenda"))
```

**the AJAX request from the delete page**:

```
let token = '{{csrf_token}}';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
    url: "{% url 'agenda:excluirReuniao' idReuniao %}",
    timeout: 7200000,
    success: function (xhr, textStatus) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ...
    }
});
```

**agenda.html**:

```
<html>
   ... (all the HTML stuff)
</html>
<script>
    var message= "{{message}}";  // gets the message from the context        

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // uses jquery-confirm to show the message to the user as an alert

        if (message!= '') {
            $.alert({
                title: 'Concluído',
                content: message,
                type: 'green'
         });
    }
    
});
</script>
```

This mechanisc works well if the first call is not done with an AJAX but by a POST form, for example.